# PHP preg_replace: PHP Error[2]: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Tags: php

trying to replace string once and getting this error would appreciate any help.

```
$link = '<a href="'.$url.'" title="'.$anchor.'">'.$anchor.'</a> ';
$text = preg_replace(/" ".$anchor." "/,"", $text,1);
```

Getting this error message:

```
Error[2]: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

Any idea? All I want is just to replace the first occurrence of text with a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$link = '<a href="'.$url.'" title="'.$anchor.'">'.$anchor.'</a> ';
$text = preg_replace("/ ".$anchor." /" ,"" , $text , 1 );
// If the spaces were intended
// OR
$text = preg_replace("/".$anchor."/" ,"" , $text , 1 );
// If you do not mean for the anchor to have a space before and after it.
```

The regular expression segment for these must be a string or an array of strings.

Comment: yeah, thanks man I just found this mistake =) and was about to post it but here you are.

Comment: This answer is completely rubbish. [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) takes arguments `mixed $pattern`, `mixed $replacement`, `string $subject`.  I'm sure he's not trying to find `$anchor` in `1` (numeric literal)...

Comment: @macek: Well, if you don't like my answer, provide one of your own. And the `1` is in the limit position. Good to see you can read the PHP.net website (I corrected the bit about it being a string, to allow for an array of strings), but you might want to read things a bit more closely next time.

Comment: @Lucanos, that's just it; _no one_ can answer this question until we know what `$anchor` and `$text` are. I gave you -1 on this to discourage these kind of hasty (and obviously wrong) answers.

Comment: $anchor = "visit website" and text just a huge text

Comment: @macek: Judging by Tim's comment on my answer, yes, yes I can.

Comment: @Tim: If this answer worked for you, can you mark it as Correct. Ta.

Comment: Lucanos was right I did not declare it right. here how I should have declare it "/ ".$anchor." /" instead of /" ".$anchor." "/

Comment: I can't have to wait another 2 minutes =)

Comment: @Lucanos, haha, your answer removes the anchor from the text. It doesn't do anything with `$link`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different delimiter, and also take advantage of double quotes in this case:

```
$text = preg_replace("~$anchor~", $link, $text, 1);
```

The previous error was caused either by your invalid syntax, or by `$anchor` containing a forward slash itself. (That would need to be escaped. With `~` as delimiter now, the `$anchor` may not contain one. Otherwise see preg_quote.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do something like this;

```
$text = "lorem ipsum dolor";

$anchor = "ipsum";

$link = '<a href="/foobar" title="'.$anchor.'">'.$anchor.'</a>';

$text = preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($anchor, '/').'/', $link, $text, 1);

echo $text;

#=> lorem <a href="/foobar" title="'.$anchor.'">'.$anchor.'</a> dolor
```

See it working here on [tehplayground.com](http://tehplayground.com/#4ec8b14ce2f10)

You'll want to use [`preg_quote()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) in the event that `$anchor` might contain some characters that need to be escaped as a regex pattern.